# difficulty with Javascript show/hide

Tags: php, javascript

I have a foreach loop in php that searches through a directory, finds any other directories, and then using hide/show in javascript, the subdirectories names are made into links that drop down to reveal the files inside of that specific subdirectory. I hope that makes sense. The problem I have is that because I am using a loop to find any present subdirectories, I can’t give each of the subdirectories a different id. As a result, all of the links have the id of the first link and when any of them are clicked, the first link always drops down. Do I need to use JQuery for this?

```
<!--Code for the javascript part:-->
<?php
<script language="javascript">
    function showOrHide(){ 
        var div = document.getElementById("showOrHideDiv");
        if (div.style.display == "block"){ 
                div.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
?>

<!-- A subdirectory has been found and is called $subDir -->
<!-- Below is the show/hide part of my html/php code -->

<a href="javascript:showOrHide();"><?php echo $subDir;?></a>
<div id="showOrHideDiv" style="display: none">

<!-- The rest of the code that prints the files from the subdirectory -->

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have `<?php ... ?>` around the `script` tags? That's not valid PHP, it's HTML! Remove the `<?php ... ?>`.

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery for this, but you would have to provide different ID's, irregardless of jQuery or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use a counter and use that to vary the IDs:

```
<a href="javascript:showOrHide(<?php echo $counter;?>);"><?php echo $subDir;?></a>
<div id="showOrHideDiv_<?php echo $counter;?>" style="display: none">
```

Then your javascript changes:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function showOrHide(num){ 
    var div = document.getElementById("showOrHideDiv_" + num);
    if (div.style.display == "block"){ 
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
      div.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: +1 good answer (and for picking up the oversight in my answer as well :D)